# Magento2 how to set multiple custom attribute

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I am creating new products via code. I want to save a product that has a custom attribute with multiple values. So the attribute property input type is a **Multiple Select (nomo_color)**. I know how to save a single attribute property via the method

> **$product->setCustomAttribute('attribute_code', id)**

But how would I do this if I should save multiple values ?

I tried iterating over the values and calling the method multiple times. This doesn't work and only saves the last value.

This is my Code

```
$product = $this->productFactory->create();
$type = $result[2];
$article = $result[1];
$size = $result[3];
$color = $result[4];

$qualities = isset($result[7]) ? $this->formatQualityText($result[7]) : [];
$colorValues = isset($result[5]) ? $this->formatColorText($result[5]) : [];

$sku = $article.'-'.$color.'-'.$size;
$name = $article . ' - ' . $color . ' - ' . $type . ' - ' . $size;
$price = (float) isset($result[6]) ? $result[6] : 0;

$product->setSku($sku);
$product->setName($name);
$product->setPrice($price);

if ( ! empty($colorValues)) {
    foreach($colorValues as $value) {
        $product->setCustomAttribute('nomo_color', $this->attributeHelper->createOrGetId('nomo_color', $value));
    }
}

if ( ! empty($color)) {
    $product->setCustomAttribute('color', $this->attributeHelper->createOrGetId('color', $color));
}

$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved my problem.

You can save custom attribute id's seperated by ',' =>  implode(',' $ids);

```
if ( ! empty($colorValues)) {
    $colorIds = [];
    foreach($colorValues as $colorValue) {
        $colorIds[] = $this->attributeHelper->createOrGetId('nomo_color', $colorValue);
    }
    $product->setCustomAttribute('nomo_color', implode(',',$colorIds));
}
```